# Creating a semantically correct table without using rowspan

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a resume with pure HTML and CSS, and want to keep it as clean as possible. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93CsQ/15/) I've built the layout I want to achieve.

This is clearly not the prettiest solution, as it breaks if the entry "Languages" is a lot longer.

Rowspan is a bit cleaner, however two issues occur:

Firstly, whenever i add a new entry to the list, I'd have to increment the colspan (I don't want to use any scripting, KISS).

Secondly, and more worryingly, the `td:first-child` selector doesn't account for the rowspan. The wreckage can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9AKM/3/)

Another approach I've tried is to use a `<ul>` and then use an `ul:before` selector to prepend a block with the grey line and the "Languages" text. A new challenge appears: setting `content` on this pseudo-element will put it ***above*** the `<ul>`.

What do you think is the cleanest, leanest way of handling this situation?

Comment: I advise you stay away from tables for layout on a website.  See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1

Comment: If you ask me, there is nothing wrong with makeing a table inside a table, maybe that could make life easyer? (Ofcours avoid using tables but, if you insist)

Comment: @kevin628 While I agree with staying away from tables for layout, I think this is a correct usage of a table. It's a matrix with headers vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @BjarkeCK Using a table within a table would, on the other hand, be using tables for layout..

Comment: @DZittersteyn Yes, but if it works, right?

Comment: @BjarkeCK Yeah, but as a resume for a Web Dev, I'd really like to keep this SUPER clean ;)

Comment: @kevin628 technically, the table i'm really going for is the following: http://jsfiddle.net/FhLNL/9/

Comment: @DZittersteyn Well, whatever works for you, I suppose.  I used something similar on a website I did once.  I think tables just complicate things if you're using them for anything more than the display of tabulated data.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @kevin628 Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your input. Problem is I've got a bit of a fascination with semantic correctness, making my life a lot harder ;).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm all for semantic correctness but there is NOTHING semantic in a div or a table. Microformats, HTML5, that's Semantics.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos While I agree that HTML5/Microformats are very strong semanics, consider the following two fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLkaH/21/,
http://jsfiddle.net/Qk3rP/6/.

While these look the same, I think you'll agree that they are semantically very different.

Comment: not really... I mean ok, ul is a bit better, but I think practically there's no difference.. unless you have lots of free time that is:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `divs` and `float` to make two columns? You could put whatever you wanted on the right side, table, `ul`, anything.

**HTML**

```
<div id="resume">
    <div class="category">Skills</div>
    <div class="left">Languages</div>
    <div class="right">asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="left">Languages</div>
    <div class="right">asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>

    <div class="category">Skills</div>
    <div class="left">Languages</div>
    <div class="right">asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /> asfd<br /></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divider {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.category{
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/93CsQ/21/)

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible, but that isn't all that semantically sound. A div should (imho) be used to contain sections of a webpage.. As above, semantically I'm going for the table in http://jsfiddle.net/FhLNL/9/.

Comment: I dunno, I don't agree with your statement about `divs`. What you're doing is really pushing the limit of "tabulated" data, which is the only thing I reserve tables for. I wouldn't do a layout with them.